# Validar por el prompt el texto

Tags: javascript

Se cómo validar que el resultado del prompt sea un número y te siga pidiendo que insertes un valor hasta dar con un número.

Ahora quiero hacer lo contrario, que la validación sea por un texto, no por un número, y si detecta que el valor es un número o lo contenga, volver a pedirlo.

Hasta ahora he probado esto infructuosamente, ya que ponga texto o ponga número, el prompt no avanza:

```
var frut = prompt('Escribe el nombre de la fruta');
    while(!frut || !isNaN(frut)){
        prompt('Escribe el nombre de la fruta');
    }
```

---

**EDIT**
Teniendo en cuenta que los números que sacas por el prompt están en modo texto, lo que no quiero es que el prompt admita números.

Probé lo siguiente para dicho resultado:

```
var frut = prompt('Escribe el nombre de la fruta');
    while(/^[a-z][a-z]*/.test(frut)){
        prompt('Escribe el nombre de la fruta');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes varios problemas:

1. No guardas el resultado de llamar a prompt en la variable frut dentro del bucle.
2. La regex está mal, si quieres letras mayúsculas tendría que ser algo como `/[a-zA-Z]+$/`.
3. Llamar a test sin negar la condición hace que mientras encuentre una letra, seguirá pidiendo el dato.

Puedes probar a buscar números:

```js
let frut = prompt('Escribe el nombre de la fruta');
while(/\d/.test(frut)) { //mientras haya algún número
  console.log(frut);
  frut = prompt('Escribe el nombre de la fruta');
}
console.log(frut);
```

Comment: Brutal como siempre. Muchísimas gracias!